# Returns Internal Server Error (500) after connecting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select data from a MySQL database with PHP. Problem is, that when I try to echo out the `$result`, I get a 500 Error. When I leave out the `echo $result;`, I get a 200 OK return.
You guys gut any ideas?

Here's the PHP:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "password";
$dbname     = "test";

//establish connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check Conncetion


if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failes: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM phptesting";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo $result;

/*
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "- Name: " . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"]";
}
*/


mysqli_close($conn);
```

For your info, `$q` is just an integer with an id for testing it out.

Comment: `mysqli_conncet_error` See anything wrong there?

Comment: This is in no case a duplicate of the marked question...

Comment: @JayBlanchard I saw it, even without what you included as the typo ;-)

Comment: thanks, but fixing this typo didnt help anything.

Comment: Yeah it is a duplicate. 500 Errors can be tracked in the error logs and there are literally a dozen more that I can use as a dupe. Check your error logs for more information.

Comment: `conncetiong` - Spelling is of the utmost important in the real world; and this is the real world also.

Comment: okay i'll try my best finding out the error then.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: you're also using a GET array for Lord knows what, then commented out the loop; *why?*

Comment: @GrumpCrouton why did you change the code in the edit?

Comment: yea, `connceting`??? I'm with @Jay here, don't people know how to spell anymore?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Didn't get your comment, spelled my name wrong :) Hmm, I don't recall what I was thinking when I did that...

Comment: Apologies @GrumpyCrouton but you should never change the posted code. ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Usually I only do that to format it or remove the beginning and ending tags. Been a long day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` is used to output primitive data type such as String, Integers. 
 `$result` holds the metadata of your SQL query result.

In ur code ur trying to echo the metadata. And This caused PHP fatal error.